# Selenium webdriver with Phantomjs save_screenshot doesn't work in Docker container

Tags: selenium, docker, phantomjs

The very same code works on my local machine, but doesn't work in a Docker container. On my local machine, it saves an image of the desired website as it's supposed to. In the Docker container, it saves a .png file with the right name, but the image is only 8kB and is blank. There is no error message. The Docker container has access to the Internet because pinging google.com from the container's bash shows that Internet connection is working. Similarly, if I try to get it to show me the html from this page, it fails in Docker but succeeds on my local system. Any idea what's wrong here?

Here's the code that invokes Selenium and phantomjs:

```
def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.set_window_size(1600, 1200)
    # must give the page enough time to fully render
    driver.implicitly_wait(WAIT_TIME)
    return driver

def render_page(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)

def save_image(driver, path):
    driver.save_screenshot(path)


IMAGE_NAME = 'test_image.png'
WAIT_TIME = 10
url = 'https://www.google.com/'

driver = phantom_tools.init_driver()
render_page(driver, url)
save_image(driver, IMAGE_NAME)
```

Comment: Can you add more information to make it easier for someone to reproduce this issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Put an additional sleep and also test it with multiple URLs